# How to add button to Skype

Tags: c#, skype

How can I add a button in Skype with a function incorporated in the Skype window and not in another? I want to create a plugin that I will use in Skype without opening another window, is it possible? I've seen the Skype Developer Platform but I don't know how to use it, it can be usefull?

Comment: Yes, using Skype Platform to develop for Skype must indeed be of some help.

Comment: How can I use it? Is there a guide or any tutorial usefull?